# Forward domain to another domain in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm attempting to forward a domain in my Route 53 (aws) to another domain that exists as a different hosted zone.

For example, I've got abc.com setup as a hosted zone. I wanted to forward this domain to xyz.com, which is also a hosted zone.

For abc.com, I've got the following records in Route 53.

- 'NS' record that gets created when you create the hosted zone
- 'SOA' record that gets created when you create the hosted zone
- 'A' record that is for abc.com
- 'A' record that is for [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)

Which one should I modify and how in order to get this domain to forward to xyz.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Route53 does not natively redirects domains. There are few ways to accomplish this, but the most common one us to use S3 static hosting redirect.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/redirect-website-requests.html